# level translator IC for SPI

Tags: integrated-circuit, spi, level-translation

In my current project I am working on the scheme and need a IC with following requirements:
-   It has to be a  lever translator from 2.2V to 3.3V; 
-   It has 5 channels;
-    on 2.2V side It  has 3 inputs and 2 outputs;
-   2.2V side needs OE;
-    it is OK when 3.3V side is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnaly, I'm using the MAX3372EEKA+T for level translation.

It's a dual channel and the voltage range are from 1.2V to 5.5V.
It's bidirectionnal so you can use it as input or output.

For your project, you can put 3 of them.